# add empty xmlns to selective child nodes

Tags: xslt

I have an XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Body>
        <reinstateAccountRequest xmlns="http://abc.xyx/">
            <serviceRequestContext>
                <a>t</a>
                <b>t</b>
            </serviceRequestContext>
            <reinstateAccountInput>
                <a>t</a>
                <b>t</b>
            </reinstateAccountInput>
        </reinstateAccountRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I want to add empty `xmlns` to `serviceRequestContext` and `reinstateAccountInput` node

Result XML should look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Body>
        <reinstateAccountRequest xmlns="http://abc.xyx/">
            <serviceRequestContext xmlns="">
                <a>t</a>
                <b>t</b>
            </serviceRequestContext>
            <reinstateAccountInput xmlns="">
                <a>t</a>
                <b>t</b>
            </reinstateAccountInput>
        </reinstateAccountRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

How to write an XSLT for this

Comment: Why in hell what you do that?

Comment: actually am using UFT for testing web services and in uft when the child elements of serviceRequestContext and reinstateAccountInput are mapped from output of aother web service call.This mapping somehow results in removal of xmlns="" from these two nodes.As a result exception is thrown in the service call.thats why i was thinking of using xslt to transform the xml to required format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start off by building upon the XSLT identity template, to copy across any existing nodes

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

With this in place, you only then have to write templates where you want to make changes to the nodes. In your case, you want to change the child elements of the **reinstateAccountRequest** element, and the change you need to make is to create new elements with the same name, but no namespace.

```
<xsl:template match="abc:reinstateAccountRequest//*">
   <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:element>       
</xsl:template>
```

Where "abc" is a namespace prefix that would be defined to have the same namespace URI as in your input XML.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:abc="http://abc.xyx/">

   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="abc:reinstateAccountRequest//*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:element>       
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```